# Single item with linebreak in tListBox

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-7, listboxitem

So question is how to make items for tListBox with a linebreak inside of them (so every item should contain 2 rows). I found how to alter the item height, but still cant get it to divide an item text by linebreaks. Is it possible without hooking the whole rendering process? Maybe some WinApi native solutions??

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible without hooking the whole rendering process?

No.  A standard ListBox control does not support line breaks. You have to owner-draw the ListBox items (set the `Style` property to one of the `lbOwnerDraw...` styles, and assign an `OnDrawItem` event handler) to draw each item however you want.  You can use the Win32 [`DrawText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498.aspx) function to draw text that contains line breaks.

Comment: Yeah, know this, and i mentioned in question:
_**>>** Is it possible without hooking the whole rendering process?_

Comment: Yes, you did, and the answer to that is no.  Owner-drawing is required.